# How to append string somewhere specific in text file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a text file with this text inside it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first webpage</title>
        <style>body{background-color:white; color:black}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to append a string in between the

in the seventh line.
For example, something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first webpage</title>
        <style>body{background-color:white; color:black}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is an example</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I coded this but it's obviously wrong

```
def makeHomepage():
    f = open("webcode.html", "r")
    line = f.readlines()

    for line in f:
        if line == "<p><p>":
            print(line + "Hello World")

print(makeHomepage())
```

I've been looking for answers online for a few hours now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you need to open the file in the `r+` mode, to read *and* write to the file. Use `file.seek()` to change the current file position to the index where `<p>` occurs in the file. Then write the new text, plus the rest of the file.

```
with open('webcode.html', 'r+') as file:
    text = file.read()
    i = text.index('<p>') + 3
    file.seek(i)
    file.write('Hello World' + text[i:])
```